# how to count the values inside HTTP_SERVER_VARS['QUERY_STRING']

Tags: php

I have defined a var to be used in my forms and it grabs all the parameters automatically so that i dont have to check for them. problem is how do i count the values inside 
HTTP_SERVER_VARS['QUERY_STRING'] ?

when i do var_dump i see string(0) "" when I have no params but when i do it beings string(#) where # is the num of params. I have tried count() but it shows a value of 1 no matter how many params i put.

this is what i have set up.

```
define('PHP_SELF', htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "?". $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['QUERY_STRING']);
```

this is how i use it.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= PHP_SELF ?>">
....
</form>
```

my problem is even if there are no params the action looks like /page.php? and I want to check against the params so if no params are set then i can take out the ? mark. How would i do this?

let me know you understand what im trying to say.

Comment: Have you considered using `$_SERVER` instead of `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` ?

Comment: i didnt know i can use $_server and i just tested it gives back the same response. I am not able to count the parameters for some reason.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. What's the counting for? And why not just `count($_GET)` which is already the parsed result of `QUERY_STRING`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] !== '')
   $count = count(explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
else
   $count = 0;
```

or maybe you can do this (more simple):

```
$count = count($_GET);
```

Comment: wow thanks i didnt even think of parsing it as text. i for some reason thought it would be an array.

Answer (score 3):

The query string is the part in a URL after and including the questionmark (e.g. `?x=1` in `http://www.example.com/dir/file.php?x=1`). You should use the `$_GET` array instead of parsing `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` variable manually. For POST fields, use `$_POST`.

If you want to hide the query string part if it's empty, why not do so?

```
define(PHP_SELF,
    htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .
        ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '')
    ));
```

Note that I've moved the closing parenthese of `htmlentities` to protect against XSS from the query string.